# LINQ - Filter List to return only items that have single occurance

Tags: linq

Given I have a

```
List<int> listNum = new List<int>{1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5}
```

How can I filter to get only to return {2, 4} from the list

Comment: Please show your latest failed attempt at solving this problem independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ's way to solve this problem starts with grouping identical items, like this:

```
var groups = listNum.GroupBy(num => num);
```

Now all you need to do is filtering out groups that have multiple items:

```
var singular = groups.Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<int> listNum = new List<int>{1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5};

listNum.GroupBy(t=>t).Where(s=> s.Count() ==1).Select(i=> i.Key).Dump();
```